# Issue with google chrome experience on mac book

Tags: google-chrome, google

I am facing issues with google chrome recently on my MacBook pro M1 updated to Sonoma 14.0 OS.
When using chrome browser, some buttons and links are not clickable and refreshing the page sometimes fix the issue temporarily but again occurs in other buttons and links.

Clearing the cache didn’t fix.
Uninstalled and installing again didn’t fix the issue.

current google chrome Version: 118.0.5993.96 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Do you get a problem with those links using Safari?

Comment: Safari is working fine without any of those issues.

Comment: Have you any accessibilty settings set e.g I had this on a chrome based browser with Hover Text on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update your OS to Sonoma 14.1, which is now released.

Make sure your version of Chrome is up to date. Then see if Chrome offers any support for its users. Check that you don't have any Adware extensions.

Finally, to avoid problems with Chrome and improve the privacy and performance of your browsing, use [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com) or [FireFox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/) or Safari instead. ;-)

Comment: Vivaldi is chrome based

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, but it prides itself on privacy, and seems to be more resource efficient.

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy, Updating the OS fixed the issue. It's working fine as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem as well and I'm still on Ventura so it's not Sonoma.  What I found elsewhere was to enable GPU rasterization in Chrome.  Go to about:flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization and enable.  This fixed that particular problem immediately.  Have not seen it come back.